# Return not working inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript

```
function mapHasStops(callback) {
    app.map.mapObject.getVisibleRegion(function (bounds) {
        for (var i = 0; i < app.map.mapContent.length; i++) {
            (function (i) {
                app.map.mapContent[i].getPosition(function (position) {
                    if (bounds.contains(position)) {
                        callback(true);
                        return;
                    }
                });
            })(i);
        }
    });
}

function updateScreenContent() {
    mapHasStops(function (bool) {
        alert(bool);
    });
}
```

Despite returning immediately after a successful match, the `alert` is called multiple times (depending on how many matches it finds) when the `updateScreenContents` function is only called once. Any ideas why?

Comment: You are `return`ing from the anonymous function, which then proceeds to the next iteration of the loop...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I thought that might be the case. How would I exit the `mapHasStops` function from inside the anonymous function?

Comment: I'd do something like `var breaknow = false;`, then set `breaknow = true` in your anonymous function, and change your loop condition to `i < app.map.mapContent.length && !breaknow`

Answer (score 0):

Just fixing the code would be:

```
function mapHasStops(callback) {
    app.map.mapObject.getVisibleRegion(function (bounds) {
        var found = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < app.map.mapContent.length && !found; i++) {
            (function (i) {
                app.map.mapContent[i].getPosition(function (position) {
                    if (bounds.contains(position)) {
                        found = true;
                        callback(true);
                        return;
                    }
                });
            })(i);
        }
    });
}

function updateScreenContent() {
    mapHasStops(function (bool) {
        alert(bool);
    });
}
```

But there is probably a better way to write that function...

Comment: *found* can also be added to the *for* condition: `i < app.map.mapContent.length && !found` however *break* might be clearer. A value could also be returned by and `app.map.mapContent…()` and checked before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

A return statement only exits from its own execution context, not any outer context. In this case, the value is returned and used by *getPosition*:

```
    // Enclosing context
    (function (i) {
                                          // Function expression is passed to *getPosition*
                                          // whose return value is not assigned
        app.map.mapContent[i].getPosition(function (position) {
            if (bounds.contains(position)) {
                callback(true);
                return;
            }
        });
    })(i);
```

So the function expression starting `function (position)` is passed to the *getPosition* method, which presumably calls it. It's value is returned there and proceeds to do whatever. It doesn't return any further than that.

Answer (score -1):

Does "function (position)" pass as a callback function?
If yes the for loop won't wait for it to return thus "function (position)" was called multiple times.